# Is there a word for that which is judged or that which is valued/evaluated?

Tags: vocabulary

A judge judges the judged. Is there a synonym for this "the judged"? In other words, is there a name for the object of judgement? When I judge a proposition to be true, art to be beautiful, a defendant to be guilty or a product to be valuable, the proposition, art, defendant and product all have in common that they are judged, otherwise said, that they are the objects of judgement. So I'm asking if there is a name for this kind of thing.

Comment: @Nigel J That's not a felicitous analogy. The DO and corresponding referent of 'evaluate' can and often is the article, process etc being evaluated, and that corresponds to OP's usage. The defendant in a court case, not guilt/innocence.

Comment: Often, the _candidate_. The broadened usage to non-human referents is a bit idiosyncratic (ie doesn't always sound natural). Mrs McCarthy's award-winning strawberry scones as candidates in the next village fair competition?

Comment: @NigelJ Edwin understand what I mean and is also correct in pointing out the idiosyncratic generalization. I judge a proposition to be true, a good or service to be valuable, a defended to be guilty/innocent. What is the general term for the object of judgement. I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: That which is judged is the patient of the agent, the object relative to the subject and would be in the accusative if English were a cased language. What you're talking about seems irrelevant.